# EF6: Создание индекса для таблицы EF6 CF Migration + ODP.NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, plsql, миграция

Использую связку Oralce + EntityFramework Code First Migration.

Добавил из nuget 2 либы ODP.NET. Контекст и прочее просано удачно. Коннект устанавливается и объекты бд создаются. Когда пытаюсь создать таблицу с индексом, получаю ошибку при попытке выполнения скрипта создания индекса.
Мои действия:

1. Создаю таблицу:

   ```
   [Table("VSM_TP_REL")]
   public class DepRel
       {
       [Column("ID"), Key]
       public int Id { get; set; }

       [Column("FULLNAME", TypeName="varchar2"), Required, MaxLength(250)]
       public string FullName { get; set; }

       [Column("SEX", TypeName="varchar2"), Required, MaxLength(1), Index("IX_VSM_TP_REL")]
       public string Sex { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Как ясно из текста класса, Index аннотация должна создать мне индекс на поле
3. Создаю миграцию. Тут все нормально
4. Выполняю команду update-database -verbose. Происходит создание таблицы, но на этапе создания индекса к полю, получаю ошибку. Привожу скрипт создания индекса:

   ```
   begin
     execute immediate
     'create index "PROD"."IX_VSM_TP_REL" on "PROD"."VSM_TP_REL" ("SEX")';
   exception
   when others then
     if sqlcode <> -1408 then
       raise;
     end if;
   end;
   ```
5. А вот и текст полученной ошибки

   ```
   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException,Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.
     at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
   Type is not resolved for member 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException,Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.
   ```

**ВОПРОС 1:** Как я понял, миграцией не выполняется ни один pl/sql скрипт. Даже самый элементарный. ПОЧЕМУ?

**ВОПРОС 2:** Как обойти эту ошибку?

Дополнительная информация:

Pavel Mayorov, спасибо за совет. Я выполнил все что, вы написали и вот что получил

[image: My screen]

Как я и писал ранее, эта ошибка может возникать в том случае, если исполняется анонимный блок(в моем случае таковой имеется). После долгого гугления я нашел [возможную причину ошибки](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/executing-sql-scripts-with-oracle-odp/) - ODP.NET doesn't support CR/LF. Автор советует выполнить

```
command.CommandText = sql.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит так, как будто при попытке передать реальную ошибку происходит ошибка сериализации.

Чтобы увидеть реальную ошибку, создайте и запустите консольное приложение следующего вида:

```
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        try {
           Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ВашКонтекст, ВашаКонфигурацияМиграций>());
           var db = new ВашКонтекст();
           db.Database.Initialize(false);
           Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Разумеется, понадобится еще добавить все нужные зависимости и юзинги - это я оставляю вам. Также, возможно, вам понадобится передать строку подключения. После этого в консоли должна появиться реальная причина ошибки.